# Help decode/identify/guess this blown ceramic capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, identification, repair, ceramic, replacement

My monitor's backlight died (can still see screen with torch).

Found a blown ceramic disc capacitor. The problem is it's partly exploded over the values. I'm hoping people here might have a better guess.

The monitor is the Philips BDM4065UC.
The capacitor is off the power board.
[image: Capacitor]

And for reference here are [pictures of the board.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAv88.jpg) Can't upload them here due to 2MB filesize. The capacitor is C9818 it's in the middle top of the top of the board picture and the middle right of the bottom of the board.

Comment: It's either 220 pF or 2200 pF rated at 1 kV. Look for another similar one on the PCB that you can show if you resized the image in paint etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That part appears to be a 220pF 1kV capacitor<sup>1</sup>.  These are readily available (e.g. [from here](https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Capacitors/Ceramic-Capacitors/Ceramic-Disc-Capacitors/_/N-5g90?P=1z0x8hsZ1yp7xv3)<sup>2</sup>).  These don't typically burn up on their own<sup>3</sup> though so there's likely an additional fault on the board that caused this cap to fail.

You should also take a look at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/475577/differences-between-220pf-1000v-capacitors) which is very similar to yours.

---

<sup>1</sup> `22` is the multiplier, `1` is the number of zeroes after it, `K` is usually the tolerance (probably ±10%), value is in pF. Thus `221K` == 220pF ±10%.

<sup>2</sup> The part links go to [Mouser](https://mouser.com) (my preferred distributor) but [Digikey](https://digikey.com), [Newark](https://newark.com), or [RS](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/) are also reputable suppliers.  I'd avoid purchasing any parts from the likes of ebay, Amazon, or Ali Express.

<sup>3</sup> Edit: Having taken another look at the photos you provided it looks like that the failed cap is part of an overvoltage protection circuit.  I can't read the markings on the diode on the bottom of the board to determine precisely what it is (type, voltage, etc.)<sup>3</sup>.

Suffice to say it looks to me like a voltage spike came in and (based on the lack of obvious damage elsewhere on the board) the protection circuit did its job and cut power to the board (using the MOSFET `Q9801`<sup>4</sup>).  The spike, however, exceeded the voltage rating of the bypass capacitor and caused it to burn up.

My guess is the rest of the components are fine though `Q9801` may also have been damaged.  Cleaning both sides of the board around where it failed<sup>6</sup> and replacing the capacitor and maybe the MOSFET should get things working again.  One thing that you should probably do is choose a replacement capacitor with a higher voltage rating<sup>7</sup> such as [one of these](https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Capacitors/Ceramic-Capacitors/Ceramic-Disc-Capacitors/_/N-5g90?P=1z0x8hsZ1yp7xv1Z1ykkkqaZ1ykkkm9Z1ykkklaZ1ykkkjcZ1ykkkjb).  If you're not already doing so make sure your equipment is plugged into a power strip with transient voltage surge protection; that'll prevent a lot of damaging spikes from getting through.

<sup>3</sup> Based on the questioner's comment, the diode is marked `A27` which may be a [DAM1MA27](https://www.hitachi-power-semiconductor-device.co.jp/en/products/diode/pdf/pde-dam1ma-3.pdf) or [DAM3MA27](https://www.hitachi-power-semiconductor-device.co.jp/en/products/diode/pdf/pde-dam3ma-3.pdf) 27V zener.  That voltage seems odd though given that it's on the mains (high-voltage) side of the circuit. I've probably misidentified it.

<sup>4</sup> Per the questioner's comment, `Q9801` is a Toshiba [K13A65U](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/901623/ToshibaSemiconductor/K13A65U/1) which has been discontinued by the manufacturer.  It's hard to choose a suitable replacement without doing a detailed analysis of the circuit.  The manufacturer [recommends](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/semiconductor/product/mosfets/400v-900v-mosfets/detail.TK13A65U.html#recommended) either the TK11A65W ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TK11A65W_datasheet_en_20140512-1916254.pdf), [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TK11A65WS5X?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduitAymi2JhSCVj3NREOVxjgbnG5wuml%252BkY%3D)) or the TK380A65Y ([datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TK380A65Y_datasheet_en_20161115-1916089.pdf), [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TK380A65YS4X?qs=d0WKAl%252BL4KZwXyNmAT%2FkfA%3D%3D)) as possible replacements.  Of the two, the TK11A65W would be my choice given its lower on resistance and higher current rating.  When choosing a replacement, the main parameters to try to match are probably the pinout, `Vdss`, `Vgss`, `Id`, `V(br)dss`, `Vth`, and `Rds(on)` with `Qq` being less important.  The [part found by the questioner](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TK155A65ZS4X?qs=vEM7xhTegWgfZC1GjjWk9g%3D%3D) (TK155A65Z, [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/408/TK155A65Z_datasheet_en_20190930-1919893.pdf)) also looks like a decent option.
Honestly, choosing an appropriate replacement is a whole question unto itself<sup>5</sup>.

<sup>5</sup> I'd encourage you to post such a question.

<sup>6</sup> 90% denatured or isopropyl alcohol should do fine for cleaning.

<sup>7</sup> In my experience, monitor manufacturers are notorious for combining the lowest-speced parts possible with poor thermal design.

| Top of board | Bottom of board |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Top of board] | [image: Bottom of board] |

Comment: Thanks for that. I was leaning towards it being 221K but I didn't know if some other value was possible. The diode on the bottom says R on top then A27. The resistors are 330. Most of the mess was actually from solder paste I used while de-soldering. Any idea if the spike was internal or external (A power pole outside our house caught fire a few weeks back and they redid the wiring then).

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop Can't be sure (what with the hole where the number was) but the kerning on the characters makes anything but 22**1**K seem unlikely.

Comment: 22 is the multiplier, 1 is the number of zeroes after it, K is usually the tolerance (probably ±10%) value is in pF.  Thus 221K == 220pF ±10%.

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop The spike would have come in through the power cord from the building mains.

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop If the Mouser post and packing charges are a bit high for such a small order, there are other reliable suppliers such as RS Components who might charge less.

Comment: @AlexHajnal Any idea what a decent substitute for the MOSFET would be, it reads K13A65U but they don't seem to be available anymore. I tried finding an equivalent but there isn't a 1:1. [Closest](https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TK155A65ZS4X?qs=vEM7xhTegWgfZC1GjjWk9g%3D%3D) I could find but has a higher Qg (23 vs 17)

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop Hard to say without doing a detailed analysis of the circuit.  See the note in my answer re: `Q9801` for my opinion.